# How to automatically select language for Qute messages

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-qute

In a web app using Quarkus, RestEasy and Qute, I've successfully created a Qute template and message bundles for different languages. However, I haven't succeeded in having it select the language automatically based on the HTTP header `Accept-Language`.

The [Qute References](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference#localization) states:

> When using [quarkus-resteasy-qute](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference#resteasy_integration)
> the locale attribute is derived from
> the the `Accept-Language` header if not set by a user.

I'm using the `quarkus-resteasy-qute` extension (in `pom.xml`) and I can see that the `Accept-Language` header is set to `Accept-Language: fr,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3`. But the page is displayed in English. So what am I missing? Is there some code I need to add?

If I explictly set the language to French (see below), it is shown in French. So the template is multi-language.

```java
@Path("/test")
public class HomeController {
    @Location("home")
    Template homeTemplate;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public TemplateInstance showHome() {
        return homeTemplate
                .instance()
                .setAttribute("locale", "fr"); // hard-coded language works
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resteasy-qute` integration does not support this feature yet. Feel free to create a feature request here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues.

You can also try to send a PR instead ;-). This JAX-RS `ContainerResponseFilter` needs to be modified: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/resteasy-classic/resteasy-qute/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/resteasy/qute/runtime/TemplateResponseFilter.java

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What does the documentation ("When using quarkus-resteasy-qute the locale attribute is derived...") refer to? When would that apply?

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is still looking for an answer especially related to the message bundles - here is my solution:

I have defined a @Qualifier to differentiate the localized message bundle from the original:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface Localized {}
```

Then I have added a producer to create the localized message bundle:

```
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerRequest;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale.LanguageRange;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory;

@ApplicationScoped
public class AppMessageProducer {

    @Produces
    @Localized
    @RequestScoped
    public AppMessages appMessages() {


        try {

            HttpServerRequest request = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance().getContextData(HttpServerRequest.class);
            String acceptLanguageHeader = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");

            if (acceptLanguageHeader != null && ! "".equals(acceptLanguageHeader)) {
                List<LanguageRange> languageRanges = LanguageRange.parse(acceptLanguageHeader);

                for (LanguageRange lr : languageRanges) {

                    try {

                        return MessageBundles.get(AppMessages.class, io.quarkus.qute.i18n.Localized.Literal.of(lr.getRange()));

                    } catch(IllegalStateException ex) {}

                }

            }

            // No matching locale found. Let's return the default
            return MessageBundles.get(AppMessages.class);

        } catch(Exception ex) {

            // This is the last ditch attempt to return anything.

            return MessageBundles.get(AppMessages.class);

        }

    }

}
```

Please note that the Accept-Language header is accessed through ResteasyProviderFactory. You may have to adapt this in case you need to get the language header from somewhere else. `java.util.Locale.LocaleRange.parse()` should be able to parse an RFC 7231, Sec. 5.3.5 language preference.

Finally, all you have to do is:

```
@Inject
@org.acme.Localized
AppMessages messages;
```

and you should get a localized version if an Accept-Language header is available.

If you are using Qute templates you may have success using

```
homeTemplate.instance().setAttribute("locale", lr.getRange());
```

but I have not tested this. You will have to test how the template instance will react if an unsupported locale is requested.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you're using resteasy-reactive:

If setting the locale manually works, then why don't you do something like this:

```java
@Path("/test")
public class HomeController {
    @Location("home")
    Template homeTemplate;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public TemplateInstance showHome(@RestHeader("Accept-Language") String locales) {
        return homeTemplate
                .instance()
                .setAttribute("locale", parseLocale(locales)); 
    }

   private String parseLocale(String locales) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(locales)) {
            return "en";
        } 

        // will contain Map<Float, String> 
        // example: [0.8:eng,du], [1.0:fr] etc. last entry in map contains highest weight
        var map = Arrays.stream(locales.split(","))
                    .map(String::trim)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                            k -> {
                                var split = k.split(";");
                                return split.length == 2 ? Float.valueOf(split[1].split("=")[1]) : 1.0f;
                            },
                            () -> new TreeMap<>(),
                            mapping(v -> v.split(";")[0], joining(","))));

        return map.lastEntry().getValue().split(",")[0];       
   }
}
```